# 'selected' attribute for options doesn't reset inside if else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, html-select

I am trying to use an if else statement to add 'selected' to an option from the select menu. The only problem I have is that I'm not sure why once I go back to value 'top' option[1] is still 'selected'. It's like the first if doesn't execute the condition, although i see if i do the console log it does change to the first if...

```
<select id='selectdesign'>
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="jeans">jeans</option>
</select>


<select id='selectmenu'>
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">top-blue</option>
    <option value="2">top-pink</option>
    <option value="3">bottoms-red</option>
    <option value="4">bottoms-violet</option>
</select>
function selectOption(element) {
        if (element.value == 'top') {
             console.log('if');
             option[2].setAttribute('selected', true);
        } else if (element.value == 'jeans') {
             console.log('else if');
             option[1].setAttribute('selected', true);  
        }
    }
```

i am calling the selectOption function on selectDesign on change

Comment: show your html code also

Comment: Where is the `option` variable defined? Please [edit] the question to show all of the relevant code. In any case, you can set the current value of a select element by setting its `.value` property directly, you don't need to mess around setting the `'selected'` attribute of an individual option element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the right value of the select element, like

```
element.options[element.selectedIndex].value
```

and use

```
document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex = 1;
```

for setting an index of the options.

```js
function selectOption(element) {
    if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'top') {
        document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'jeans') {
        document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex = 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectdesign" onchange="selectOption(this);">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="jeans">jeans</option>
</select>
<select id="selectmenu">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">top-blue</option>
    <option value="2">top-pink</option>
    <option value="3">bottoms-red</option>
    <option value="4">bottoms-violet</option>
</select>
```

Version with an object for preselecting options.

```js
function selectOption(element) {
    var indices = {
            top: 1,
            jeans: 3,
        },
        value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value

    if (value in indices) {
        document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex = indices[value];
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectdesign" onchange="selectOption(this);">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="jeans">jeans</option>
</select>
<select id="selectmenu">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">top-blue</option>
    <option value="2">top-pink</option>
    <option value="3">bottoms-red</option>
    <option value="4">bottoms-violet</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I wanted.